# Selenium Webdriver (Java) - using AND/OR conditions in XPATH

Tags: selenium, xpath

I have HTML with different div's an span's inside:

```
<div class="test1">
    <div class="test2">
        <span title="Time">Today 11:12am</span>
    </div>
    <div class="test3">
        <span class="test4">Windows 7 64 bit</span>
        <span class="test5">Something</span>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="test6">
    <div class="test2">
        <span title="Time">Today 11:15am</span>
    </div>
    <div class="test3">
        <span class="test4">Windows 8 64 bit</span>
        <span class="test5">Something</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

I want to find an elements using XPATH by choosing a particular text from different span's. For instance, I need to find an element where is true : **"Today"** text and **"Windows 7"** text.

So, I've tried this statement :

```
//div[@class="test1"]/div[contains(span,'Today') and contains(span,'Windows')]
```

But this is not working. I've tried to use OR inside, it's working only for one true statement.

Are there others options?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
//div[.//span[contains(text(), 'Today')] and .//span[contains(text(), 'Windows 7')]]
```

Would work. The `[expression]` you specify can literally be anything, so you can stuff another element search within there. The `.` character is also key here, ensuring the search is scoped to the current parent (i.e the `div` and not the entire document).

Answer (score 0):

I think I have found the solution. It can be :

```
//div[@class="test1"]/div[contains(span,'Today')]/following::div(span,'Windows')]
```